# UITableView dynamic cells and static cells with container view

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to use few static cells and dynamic ones. The problem that I need also container view that includes page view controller. Is this possible to achieve structure like that:

```
Static cell
Static cell with ContainerView
Static cell
Dynamic cell
Dynamic cell
...
```

Comment: you should have make switch case with the indexPath.row

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil, switch is not a problem, the problem that I need dynamic cells and seems I can't use container view with dynamic views